# Undefined Index in Ajax POST or PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to add content to the following div:

```
<div id="radio-toolbar" class="radio-toolbar">

</div>
```

with this AJAX sript:

```
$('#part_code').keyup(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "binlist.php",
        data: {text: $(this).val()},
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',        
        success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#radio-toolbar").html(data);
                }
        });
    });
```

The input I get the data from is this one. When text it written, the ajax script triggers:

```
<input type="text" name="part_code" id="part_code" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $part;?>">
```

Binlist.php code does some checks in SQL Server and then writes HTML code.
If I hard set the $part_code_for_bin variable it works, but when I try to get it from POST, I get the error "Undefined index: part_code"

```
<?php

include 'code\database.php';
include 'code\plant.php';

//$part_code_for_bin = '1020';
//$part_code_for_bin = '116-SIG-30622A-TSM260A';

$part_code_for_bin = $_POST['part_code'];

if(isset($part_code_for_bin)) { 

    $sql_binlist= "SELECT BIS_BIN FROM R5BINSTOCK WHERE BIS_PART = '$part_code_for_bin' and BIS_STORE = '$store' and BIS_PART_ORG = '$org'";

    $bins = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_binlist, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static'));
    $bins_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($bins);

    if ($bins_count > 1) { 

        $result_bins = array();
        $i = 0;

        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($bins, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $result_bins[] = $row['BIS_BIN'];
            ?>
                <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $result_bins[$i]?>" name="radioBin" value="<?php echo $result_bins[$i]?>" onclick="write_bin('<?php echo $result_bins[$i]?>');">
                <label for="<?php echo $result_bins[$i]?>"><?php echo $result_bins[$i]?></label>

            <?php
            $i++;
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Well. Why **would** there be part_code in there? `data: {text: $(this).val()},`. You don't define `part_code`, only `text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors:

1. You define `text` in your Ajax request but try to access `part_code` in PHP.

   `data: {part_code: $(this).val()},`
2. You first try to save the POST value to a variable and then check if it is existing. You have to to do the `isset()` first before saving it to a variable.

   `if(isset($_POST['part_code'])) {
     $part_code_for_bin = $_POST['part_code'];`

Comment: I am ashamed I didn't see that... thank you.